# Adding componentDidMount to React component results in syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my home component has:

```
const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <Head title="Home" />
    <Nav />

    <div className="container o_block u_blue">
      <div className="notification">
        This container is <strong>centered</strong> on desktop.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)

export default Home
```

and I'm trying to add some DOM manipulation into that component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  let nav = document.querySelector('#'+burger.dataset.target);
  burger.addEventListener('click', function(){
    burger.classList.toggle('is-active');
    nav.classList.toggle('is-active');
  });
}

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <Head title="Home" />
    <Nav />

    <div className="container o_block u_blue">
      <div className="notification">
        This container is <strong>centered</strong> on desktop.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)

export default Home
```

but unfortunately I am getting a:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ";" (8:20)

what am I doing wrong and where should I put the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home is a presentational component in your code. Which means a presentational component is like a pure function in Java Script. A Presentational component doesn’t call any React life cycle method and doesn’t modify React state. It only takes props and returns jsx elements. This is also called as stateless component in react.

If you want to play with React life cycle methods then you should go with statefull component.

componentDidMount is one of React life cycle method so it’s not accessible in presentational or functional components in React.

Edit:

If you want to do DOM manipulation before component initial render then do DOM manipulation in componentWillMount() method but please see this method is deprecated in latest React versions.

If you want to do DOM manipulation after first render  then do that in componentDidMount() method. This is the one wr you also make axios calls and do setState accordingly. I would recommend you to go with componentDidMount().

```
  import React, { Component} from "react";

  export default class Home extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
       let burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
       let nav = document.querySelector('#'+burger.dataset.target);
        burger.addEventListener('click', function(){
         burger.classList.toggle('is-active');
         nav.classList.toggle('is-active');
        });
       }
      render(){
         return(
          <div>
           <Head title="Home" />
           <Nav />
          <div className="container o_block u_blue">
             <div className="notification">
                This container is <strong>centered</strong> on desktop.
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    )
    }
   }
```

Please excuse me if there are any typo error because I am answering in my mobile

Comment: I just want to call some DOM manipulation, is there a conventional way where to put it once the document has been served.

Comment: thanks, but when I try I'm getting a `Cannot call a class as a function` not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You have to change your component completely like I mentioned in my answer. Please check my answer

Comment: @supersize glad to see my answer is helpful to you. Thanks for accepting my answer. Kindly do upvote as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your component into a class-based component, like this :

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {

   render() {
       // Return the JSX code
   }

   componentDidMount() {
       // Your init code
   }

}
```

But I really suggest you to take a look at the official React doc as it's a fairly simple mistake.

Comment: not working, I'm getting a `Cannot call a class as a function` with your example

Comment: @supersize you should use a React component as a React component, and not as a function.

Comment: Not sure what that means?

Comment: I forgot to add the "extends React.Component" to the class.